# How to prevent clang-format from adding a single semicolon to a new line?

Tags: c++, coding-style, clang, clang-format

I have this line of code in C++

```
while (fread(pixel_array++, sizeof(byte), 3, fp));
```

but when I use clang-format, it splits the semicolon and add it into a new line

```
while (fread(pixel_array++, sizeof(byte), 3, fp))
    ;
```

I don't like this kind of style, and I just prefer to keep the original one.

How should I modify my clang-format configuration? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

clang-format 5.0 currently doesn't recognize that type of loop. Unfortunately as of clang-format version 5, you won't get a setting that does what you need.

Looking up the [Clang Format Style Options](http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), the closest that I've found is `AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true`, but that setting doesn't recognize the loop condition as being the body of the loop.

As long as clang-format doesn't recognize those kinds of loops, what I'd do is to mark it your code with `// clang-format off` and then `// clang-format on` around your block of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a trade-off way to do this.

Comment: Jan 2022, this is still the case. I would have thought by now `while(1);` or `for(;;);` would be accepted, but appanently not. Another option not discussed is `while(1) continue;` which to me at least proves the intention is a single line loop.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently this is not possible, but a workaround could be to replace the semicolon with an empty block. If both `AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine` and `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine` are set, than it will be formatted as

```
while (fread(pixel_array++, sizeof(byte), 3, fp)) {}
```

Answer (score -6):

fread does not return bool and empty while loop makes no sense. So it would be better to rewrite your code as

```
for(;;)
{
    auto const read_bytes_count{fread(pixel_array, sizeof(byte), 3, fp)};
    if((sizeof(byte) * 3) != read_bytes_count)
    {
        // probably deal with error handling...
        break;
    }
    ++pixel_array;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question about clang-format configuration. In addition, fread will return 0 when fp has reached EOF, and program will jump out of while loop, but that is not the point.

Comment: fread can return any value less than or equal to requested bytes count. If it returns 1 or 2 you will be left in uninitialized data, and even if it returns 0 it doesn't necessary mean that EOF was reached. So error checking is mandatory. I indeed didn't answer about clang-format, but that's because you don't really have a problem with it. Your problem is empty loop body.

Comment: I indeed don't think any problem exists in my code. I have already got the size of the file in the previous code, and also properly initialized my array. The way I read file like this is out of special needs. This is just a little part of my code, you can visit [this link](https://github.com/KaitoHH/AnyCodeToBmp/blob/master/bmp.c#L42) to see all my code if you're curious. At last, I would still like to know the way of clang-format configuration.

Comment: Which version of clang-format are you using? I try you code in clang-format 4.0.1. And clang-format keeps your code unchanged.