# How can I make clang-format in VS Code place a semicolon after an empty loop onto the same line?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, clang

Is it possible to force VS Code to leave the semicolon in place?
Instead of having this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    ;
```

To have this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++);
```

I am struggling with settings

```
"C_Cpp.clang_format_style":  { 
    BasedOnStyle: WebKit,  
    ColumnLimit: 120, 
},
```

**Update / Temprorarily Fix**

Appears that (thanks to @krisz) a workaround using {} is possible with clang
[How to prevent clang-format from adding a single semicolon to a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198429/how-to-prevent-clang-format-from-adding-a-single-semicolon-to-a-new-line)

After several hours, I found that vcFormat (also clang based if I understood well) is working fine, so, I dropped clang

```
{
    "C_Cpp.formatting": "vcFormat",
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++);` doesnt make any sense, its an empty for loop with nothing executed.

Comment: it's make perfectly sense. it's a inline delay on embeded systems.

Comment: @orfruit This code will optimize out on any non-zero level of optimization. It's a bad idea to rely on this as a delay mechanism.

Comment: Aside: your desired formatting looks like an error that frequently appears as a problem in posts here. Seeing it that way, I would tend to see it as a mistake at first. I'd be more likely to consider the first formatting to indicate that it was being done on purpose rather than in error.

Comment: Guys, please comment to topic only. The same as good will be while(1) which will be the same WRONG formatted.

Comment: and no, it's not a bad idea at all. the MCU will run at precise cycles and as long as you don;t touch -Os, -Ofast, etc will provide precise results. Hard to scale to meaningful time units but precise. And very good for debug purposes.

Comment: find a different method to sleep a number of micro/milli-seconds for this platform, if you move to a different version of CPU or compiler your timing will be of.

Comment: The example of an optimization-unstable delay is bad.  However there are perfectly useful loops with empty bodies, so the question is still reasonable.